# No module named 'gensim.sklearn_api' how to resolve

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, gensim

Im little confuse i would like use texthero library for some pca analysis. But when i trying run my code :

```
import texthero as hero
import pandas as pd


df['pca']=(df['clean_tweet'].pipe(hero.clean).pipe(hero.do_tfidf).pipe(hero.do_pca))
hero.scatterplot(df, col='pca', color='topic', title="PCA BBC Sport news")
```

I get error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim.sklearn_api
```

But when i put !pip show gensim. i got

```
Name: gensim
Version: 4.0.1
Summary: Python framework for fast Vector Space Modelling
Home-page: http://radimrehurek.com/gensim
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the module "gensim.sklearn_api" has been removed with version 4 of Gensim. Try downgrading Gensim's version.

```
python -m pip install gensim==3.8.3
```

Reference: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4